Package options completion in AucTeX, LaTeX
Is it possible to have auto-completion for options of packages in LaTeX, or at least list the options somewhere. I'm using texlab LSP, it doesn't work with options it seems. I just wonder what people usually do to look up the options. Is it just consulting the manual?

"Is it just consulting the manual?" - that's what I do, but if there is a language server that can do that, I might use it. OTOH, I don't have to do it often, so looking it up in the manual works okay.

At the moment, I was just looking at the pgf/tikz manual, I run pdf-occur on it with search pattern /tikz/ which gives me the list of the options, I can use a vertico line search on the occur buffer and then go to the pdf bit. I suppose this can be automated. But, I don't think it works for all packages, wouldn't have that clean a search pattern.

The pattern actually was "^/tikz/".

In general, AUCTeX supports completion for package options for which it has an AUCTeX style.  The completion is provided:

when you insert the usepackage macro with C-c C-m usepackage RET graphicx RET where you're asked about options and you get this:


or as in-buffer completion which looks like this (with corfu installed):




The same applies also when you enter macros or environments provided by packages where AUCTeX has a style for.  Taking again the package graphicx, you can hit C-c C-m includegraphics RET and AUCTeX asks for the optional key=val argument which look like this:

The in-buffer completion of it looks like this:

Note that the above is provided by AUCTeX and works without a LSP server.
In case of TikZ, I'm afraid the AUCTeX support is rather weak (i.e., quite rudimentary), so probably you won't see the completion above which is shown for the graphicx package as an example.

Thank you for your input. I actually meant more along the lines of having completion for options for commands and environments provided by packages, such as options for \draw in tikzpicture etc.

@Arktik - See the updated answer.
